# How to add a best-fit non-linear line to a plot

Tags: r, plot

The following dataset shows a power-law relationship:

```
x = 0.12, 0.46, 0.22, 0.68, 1.25 
y = 0.042, 0.075, 0.055 0.089, 0.116
```

where `y = ax^b` and `a = 0.1053` and `b = 0.433`

I fit the model as such:

```
model <- lm(log(y)~ log(x))
```

and get the summary results `summary(model)`.

I plot the data using: `plot(x, y, log = "x")`

How do I show the power-fit line on the graph?

I've tried lm() but got nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

After fitting the model `lm(log(y)~log(x))` we could extract the coefficients and then plot the power-law relationship.

```
x <- c(0.12, 0.46, 0.22, 0.68, 1.25)
y <- c(0.042, 0.075, 0.055, 0.089, 0.116)


model <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x))
plot(x, y, log = "x", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")


a <- exp(coef(model)[1])
b <- coef(model)[2]

curve(a * x^b, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: `predict` works more reliably and is easier to use

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment above, in order to plot the confidence limits, you will need to use the `predict()` function.

Using base R:
Note: **linear** x & y coordinates.

```
x = c(0.12, 0.46, 0.22, 0.68, 1.25)
y = c(0.042, 0.075, 0.055, 0.089, 0.116)

model <- lm(log(y)~ log(x))
summary(model)

plot(x, y)
curve(exp(model$coefficients[1]) * x^model$coefficients[2], add = TRUE, col = "red")

#create data from prediction (20 points in range)
df<-data.frame(x=seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 20))
prediction <- predict(model, df, interval = "confidence")
#plot prediction - dashed lines
lines(df$x, exp(prediction[,2]), lty=2)
lines(df$x, exp(prediction[,3]), lty=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In base R:

```
x = c(0.12, 0.46, 0.22, 0.68, 1.25)
y = c(0.042, 0.075, 0.055, 0.089, 0.116)
a = 0.1053
b = 0.433
plot(x,y, log = "x")
curve(a*x^b, add = TRUE)
```

### [image]

in ggplot:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y))+
    geom_point() + 
    scale_x_log10()+
    stat_function(fun = ~a*.x^b)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. any idea how to also add the confidence intervals for a and b to the plot?